# Conversion error in WF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

I'm working in a WF project... This is a part of my StatusDesigner.xaml.cs file:

```
 ............
 <sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <sapc:ArgumentToExpressionConverter x:Key="ArgumentToExpressionConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
 .......... 
 <sapv:ExpressionTextBox
      HintText="Add Description"
      Expression="{Binding Path=ModelItem.description, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter}}"
      OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}"
      UseLocationExpression="True" Margin="107,157,7,17" MaxLines="1" FontWeight="Normal" />
 ................
```

This is a ExpressionTextBox that I use to get for example issuer.DESCRIPTION...

this is my the StatusActivity.cs:

```
 public String description { get; set; }
........
  SqlCommand proc = new SqlCommand("Add_Workflow_Status", conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    proc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 .......
  proc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RESULT_CHAR", description);
```

Now, When I do issuer.DESCRIPTION a error message displayed:

*ArgumentException: Object of type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicReference`1
[System.Double]` cannot be converted to type 'System.Double'.*

It's weird..... Error to convert System.Double to System.Double?